# Update record if exist, else insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, record

I know, this question was asked many times and answered as well..
But, my problem is more specific and i couldn't found a proper solution.

My table (named as pages) is like that;

```
id (int)
title (text)
content (text)
slug (text)
```

I need to update my record if slug (**i've converted it unique**) is same as posted.

I mean i need to update/insert my record **based** on *slug* record.

Eg. current data:

```
  id  |  title  |  content  |  slug  |
--------------------------------------
  1  |  MainPage| some html | mainpage
```

if posted data has `title=ChildPage, content=html.., slug=mainpage` then i need to update previous record (title and content records), but if data has `title=MainPage, content=html.., slug=other_slug` then i need to insert this data as new with a new id.

**UPDATE**

Slug record was converted to UNIQUE key.

Comment: You said that the column is not constrained with UNIQUE... why not? I mean, are you willing to? There is a handy mechanism in MySQL if it can be UNIQUE

Comment: update previous record based on what?

Comment: If slug isn't unique what do you intend to happen if there are multiple instances of the slug when you update?

Comment: Really simple to do if you have UNIQUE or PRIMARY index

Comment: I'am really newbie in MySQL and i supposed (read on some places) that text field cannot be Unique/Autoincrease, maybe(probably) i am wrong.

Comment: I added UNIQUE property on slug record and i've updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appropriate thing I can imagine is to create a unique index on the slug column

```
ALTER TABLE pages ADD UNIQUE KEY slug;
```

The reason is simple: if this is not unique-constrained, there may be more than one slug with "mainpage"... which one should be updated??

then use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause:

```
INSERT INTO pages 
VALUES (NULL, $title, $content, $slug) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content=$content
```

Comment: after converting slug record to Unique Key, it works as i expected. Thanks for your help and all others.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE pages ADD UNIQUE KEY slug;` caused errors for me with MySQL. I had already created an index on that column - not sure if that made any difference. The following worked for me: `ALTER TABLE pages ADD UNIQUE (slug);`