# update table if ID exits otherwise insert new record?

Tags: php

I have problem in updating the  table
My table consists two Id's one is primary key and i am inserting the record by using second Id.
I am wanted too update the table if second id exits.
any help..

Answer (score 2):

select using the second id. if any rows returned run update statement else run insert statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax in MySQL. [Read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

If you are looking for a PHP solution Make a SELECT query 1st and check whether particular row exists. If exists UPDATE the values else INSERT the data.

Also read

[If Record Exists, Update Else Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630332/if-record-exists-update-else-insert)

[Update record if exist, else insert in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404243/update-record-if-exist-else-insert-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

First execute "SELECT" clause in the table, if data exist then execute "UPDATE" else "INSERT".

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("select second_id from table where second_id=".$the_second_id);
if(mysql_num_rows >0) { 
mysql_query("update table set column1=value1,column2=value2,... where second_id=".$the_second_id);
}
else{
mysql_query("insert into table(column1,column2,...) values(value,value2,...) ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = mysql_query('select * from my_table where second_id = '.$second_id);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
     mysql_query('update my_table set field = '.$value .' where second_id = '.$second_id);
 }
 else{
      mysql_query("insert into my_table (field1, field2...) values ('".$value1."', '".$value2."')");
 }
```